# Contour plots using a function

Tags: matplotlib, contour

I am stuck with the following problem;

I have to do a contour plot of a function of two variables chi2(X,Y) in a certain point (chi=2.3). I have tried many ways but I still do not know  how to do it. For instance, I have done the following:

```
  import numpy as np
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  from function import chi2  # Two variable function imported from another file

  x = np.arange(-2,2,0.02)
  y = np.arange(0,1.5,0.02)

  X,Y= np.meshgrid(x,y)

  Z = chi2(X,Y)

  plt.figure()
  CS = plt.contour(X,Y,Z)
  plt.clabel(CS,inline=2.3, fontsize=10)
  plt.show()
```

The error obtained is that the Supplied function does not return a valid float. But I can print values and work using that function, so I don't know what is exactly the problem.

Thank you in advance.

Bernat.

Comment: When reporting about an error, you need to include the traceback. You also need to include a [mcve]. Here, we miss the chi2 function. However this function, together with how you call it, is the source of the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use a generic function, the key is to `vectorized` it first.

for example

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x, y):
    return 5 * x ** 2 + 2 * y + 8

v_func = np.vectorize(f)    # major key!

x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-5, 5, 100),
                   np.linspace(-5, 5, 100))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.contour(x, y, v_func(x, y))
plt.show()
```

you should get something like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As long as no verifiable code is given in the question, here is a working solution:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

chi2 = lambda x,y: 2*(np.sin(x*4)+1)*np.sin(np.sqrt(y*4)+x)

x = np.arange(-2,2,0.02)
y = np.arange(0,1.5,0.02)

X,Y= np.meshgrid(x,y)

Z = chi2(X,Y)

plt.figure()
CS = plt.contour(X,Y,Z, [2.3])
plt.clabel(CS,inline=True, fontsize=10)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I found the mistake. With your example I could see that the problem was my function and not the contour plot itself. Thank you!